# Is there a way to set "array of strings" as a type for a parameter in a function?

Tags: python, list, types, parameters

I want to check right at the passing of the arguments to a function if the argument is an array of strings.

Like setting a type to the parameter of the function to "array of string".
But I don't want to loop through the array looking for none-string elements.

Is there a type like this?

Comment: You can use typing and http://mypy-lang.org/, but this is just for checking them while developing, the code would still "run" anyway. Best way to enforce them is to check it properly in the function.

Comment: You can't avoid looping through the whole list. You have to look at every element and check if it's a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will a lambda function work?

```
def check_arr_str(li):

    #Filter out elements which are of type string
    res = list(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x,str), li))

    #If length of original and filtered list match, all elements are strings, otherwise not
    return (len(res) == len(li) and isinstance(li, list))
```

The outputs will look like

```
print(check_arr_str(['a','b']))
#True
print(check_arr_str(['a','b', 1]))
#False
print(check_arr_str(['a','b', {}, []]))
#False
print(check_arr_str('a'))
#False
```

If an exception is needed, we can change the function as follows.

```
def check_arr_str(li):

    res = list(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x,str), li))
    if (len(res) == len(li) and isinstance(li, list)):
        raise TypeError('I am expecting list of strings')
```

Another way we can do this is using `any` to check if we have any item in the list which is not a string, or the parameter is not a list (Thanks @Netwave for the suggestion)

```
def check_arr_str(li):

    #Check if any instance of the list is not a string
    flag = any(not isinstance(i,str) for i in li)

    #If any instance of an item  in the list not being a list, or the input itself not being a list is found, throw exception
    if (flag or not isinstance(li, list)):
        raise TypeError('I am expecting list of strings')
```

Comment: Thanks! Glad to help! If the answer looks good to you, please consider marking it as accepted and upvote it @TeodoroMendes :)

Comment: hmmm great, I liked this. Maybe I found a way to further decrease the size of your code:

if list(filter(lambda x: not isinstance(x,str), li)):
        raise TypeError('I am expecting list of strings')

Thank you!

Comment: This might not work if you just pass a single string, can you try it out ?

Comment: Ill left this as a note for further readers: This version is ok, but lack of lazynes and will make evaluate the full list everytime. If you were concerned about iterating the whole list, this will do it everytime, and you are building an intermediate list in memory when is totally unnecessary.

Comment: I tried and it worked! Did you notice all my changes? I now receive a list of the objects that are NOT an instance of string at the filter function. And then, if the list exists, there is a wrong element there. Even with passing a single string it works.

Comment: @Netwave I ended up realising that I must iterate the list until I find some error, worst case: there is no error (or is this the best case? haha). But you're right in the sense that, as soon as I find some error I should break the list filtering. But I don't know if that is possible at all.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Netwave, I rethought and have added an example which uses `any` to check if we find any element which is not a string! Although I am unsure if `any` will perform better here, or `all`, I think both conditions will perform equally well?

Comment: you are just flipping the condition, so yes ofc is gonna work.

Answer (score 13):

You can use typing for recent python version (tested on 3.9), as suggested by @Netwave in the comments:

```py
def my_function(a: list[str]):
  # You code
```

Which will lint as expected:

[image: pycharm linting example]

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> isinstance(["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl"], list)
True
>>> isinstance(50, list)
False
```

You could use this inside your function in order to check if your argument is a list.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the anwser but I'm actually trying to set the entire type "list of strings" (I said 'array' earlier but is 'list' actually). Set only string type, can do. Set only list type, can do. Set 'list of strings' type, can't do.

Answer (score 0):

The way to make it bullet proof is to check them in the function (sadly iterating over the elements), but using `all` with a comprehension makes the evaluation lazy and will stop in the first element that is not a string instance:

```
def foo(my_str_list):
    is_list = isinstance(my_str_list, list) 
    are_strings = all(isinstance(x, str) for x in my_str_list)
    if not is_list or not are_strings:
        raise TypeError("Funtion argument should be a list of strings.")
    ...
```

Comment: Great, thanks. In this case actually I would raise a `TypeError` because I'm trying to tell the callers of the function that the argument type must be a list of strings.

Comment: Indeed, the `TypeError` makes much more sense here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
l = ["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl"]  
isinstance(l, list) and all(isinstance(i,str) for i in l)
```

the output:

```
In [1]: a = ["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl"]                                        

In [2]: isinstance(a, list) and all(isinstance(i,str) for i in a)               
Out[2]: True

In [3]: a = ["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl",2]                                      

In [4]: isinstance(a, list) and all(isinstance(i,str) for i in a)               
Out[4]: False
```

Comment: This is correct either, and afterwards raise the TypeError. Thanks.